# Access to fetch at 'https://test1' from origin 'https://test2' has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cors, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have transferred the API and the PWA of my Blazor project to a web server, now I get the following error:
'Access to fetch at 'Access to fetch at 'https://test1' from origin 'https://test2' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.'

This error always occurs when a POST endpoint of the API is used, with GET endpoints there is no problem.

I have already tried everything possible in the Program.cs of the API, my current code looks like this:

```
namespace Test_API
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

            builder.Services.AddControllers();

            var specificOrigins = "AppOrigins";
            builder.Services.AddCors(options => {
                options.AddPolicy(name: specificOrigins,
                                  policy =>
                                  {
                                      policy.WithOrigins("https://test2")
                                            .AllowAnyHeader()
                                            .AllowAnyMethod()
                                            .AllowCredentials()
                                            .WithExposedHeaders("Content-Disposition")
                                            .WithExposedHeaders("Content-Type");
                                  });
            });

            builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
            builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

            var app = builder.Build();

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI();

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseCors(specificOrigins);

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.MapControllers();

            app.Run();
        }
    }
}
```

So far, however, I have not come up with a solution. I really hope that someone can help me.

Kind regards

Comment: The code looks OK-ish, are you sure about those URLs and what does the network tab in dev-tools show?

Comment: I didn't want to enter the correct URLs, so I just wrote 'test' there.

Comment: The browser should send `OPTIONS` request before `POST`. Please check its response header's `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` value.

Comment: You can't change CORS policy.  Only a network admin can fix issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource—when trying to get data from a REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43871637/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-whe)

Answer (score 1):

Since your code looks like correct, it's hard to say what happened. You can try to enable `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors` log first.

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors": "Debug"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Hope we can find more details from the windows output.

[image]

**【optional】Here are two common ways to solve this problem, I hope it can help you.**

You are missing `app.UseRouting();`. The correct order should be like below:

[The call to UseCors must be placed after UseRouting, but before UseAuthorization.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-8.0#cors-with-named-policy-and-middleware)

```
        var app = builder.Build();

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI();

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        // add this line
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseCors(specificOrigins);

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.MapControllers();

        app.Run();
```

If it is still not working, please try to comment `app.UseHttpsRedirection();` or use it like below:

```
        // add this line
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseCors(specificOrigins);
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseAuthorization();
```